# Eclipse reporting errors on arrays for Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse

I'm trying to get a 3D array initialized for a game I'm working on, after multiple syntax changes I couldn't figure out how to get it to work! What I started with was:

```
public class AnimationView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {//Create bitmaps.
Bitmap bitmapGoal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.goal);
Bitmap bitmapOrig = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrig, 150, 150, true);
//initialize the canvas.
private Canvas c;
private int score[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
public int numBalls = 1;
//we support up to 4 balls. thus each array is 4 bit.
private int ballX[] = {0, 200, 400, 600};
private double ballY[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
private double dirV[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
private int dirH[] = {30, 30, 30, 30};
private static final int SCALE = 10;
private double elasticity = .6;
private int rotationNow[] = {5, 5, 5, 5};
private int rotationDraw[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};


class AnimationThread extends Thread {
//Are we running currently?
private boolean mRun;
    //layer 1 is how many balls, 4 layers deep.
    //layer 2 is which ball we're talking about, either 1, 2, 3, or 4 layers deep, depending on layer 1.
    //layer 3 is the bounds of the ball, dependent on how many there are total.
    //layer 3 is formatted x-min, x-max, y-min, y-max
    int[][][] bounds = new int[][][] {
        { {0, c.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth(), 0, c.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight()}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0} }, 
        //end first layer
        { {0, c.getWidth() / 2 - bitmap.getWidth(), 0, c.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight()}, {c.getWidth() / 2, c.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth(), 0, c.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight()}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0} }, 
        //end second layer
        { {0, c.getWidth() / 3 - bitmap.getWidth(), 0, c.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight()}, {c.getWidth() / 3, c.getWidth() * 2 / 3  - bitmap.getWidth(), 0, c.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight()}, {c.getWidth() * 2 / 3, c.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth(), 0, c.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight()}, {0, 0, 0, 0} }, 
        //end third layer
        { {0, c.getWidth() / 2, 0, c.getHeight() / 2}, {c.getWidth() / 2, c.getWidth(), 0, c.getHeight() / 2}, {0, c.getWidth() / 2, c.getHeight() / 2, c.getHeight()}, {c.getWidth() / 2, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight() / 2, c.getHeight()} }
        //end fourth, and final layer!
    };
```

Sorry about the weird formatting error. I know this doesn't help anything. There is a new line between ymax and int[][][].
You don't exactly need to look through it and understand, but this compiled and then errored out during execution. So then I tried to make a simple 3D array, I started with:

`int[][][] bounds = new int[1][1][1];

    bounds[0][0][0] = 0;`

Eclipse had it's red squiggly under the semi-colon on the first line. Saying
'Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token'

This is where it gets frustrating. Because that exact same code copy/pasted into a regular Java program works fine, but I can NOT get it to work inside an Android project. I then simplified some stuff, to this:

`int[] bounds = new int[1];

    bounds[0] = 0;`

Exact same error, exact same place! Why Eclipse?? I also tried it with "int bounds[][][]" as opposed to "int[][][] bounds" but no difference, still same error.

I've rebooted my computer, cleaned my project multiple times, restarted Eclipse. I'm out of ideas. Do you have any??

Comment: can we see more code? (probably what comes before `int[][][] bounds...`)

Comment: generally, an unclosed bracket or missing semicolon **before** this statement will cause such an error since the parser thinks that this line is also part of that previous line.

Comment: @euphoria83 see my answer. usually it's something after this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel ridiculous. After being very, very confused at why the variable couldn't initialize and why the very simple code then wouldn't compile. It turns out, though the canvas and bitmaps were available, it was infact them returning null values into the array.

So I got it working now.

Also, for my first question here, I was extremely impressed with the speediness of the solutions. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like the problem is not before, but after the code you pasted.
this assignment - `bounds[0][0][0] = 0;` is probably not in any method and this is illegal. When Eclipse sees an expression that need to be inside a method, it expects the line above to be the method declaration, so it expects `'{'` as a beginning of a method block, and not `';'`

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][][] bounds = new int[1][1][1];

bounds[0][0][0] = 0;
```

I copied these two lines and seem to be compiling fine. 
I think you might have forgot to comment the earlier declaration of bounds . (or) you might be missing braces or something like that